# SQL Bulk insert/update into a table with data from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to insert/update bulk records as follows.

Source Table 1 :

```
User ID |  Rights |
-------------------
A       |   Y     |
B       |   N     |     
-------------------
```

Source Table 2:

```
 Report ID |
 -----------
 111       |
 222       |
 ----------
```

Now I have to insert(Or, update if record exists) Cartesian product of above 'User ID' column and 'Report ID' column into another table as follows:

Target Table:

```
 User ID | Report ID| Rights |
 ------------------------------
 A       |  111     |   Y     |
 A       |  222     |   Y     |     
 B       |  111     |   N     |     
 B       |  222     |   N     |     
 ------------------------------
```

I am hitting a performance problem as the source table can have thousands of records.
Suggest me the best way to bulk insert/update.

Comment: What have you done so far that is causing performance issue? It is not obvious what that could be from your post

Comment: I tried cursor and loop each record.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create the table is:

```
select UserId, ReportId, Rights
into table3
from table1 cross join table2;
```

If the table already exists, I would suggest truncating it and inserting everything into it:

```
truncate table table3;

insert into table3(UserId, ReportId, Rights)
    select UserId, ReportId, Rights
    into table3
    from table1 cross join table2;
```

Trying to selectively add new rows seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO <Target_Table>
(UserID, ReportID, Rights)
(SELECT UserID, ReportID, Rights
FROM Table1
CROSS JOIN Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (ID varchar(10),Name varchar(10))
insert into @t (ID,Name)values ('A','Y')
insert into @t (ID,Name)values ('B','N')

declare @tt table (RepID varchar(10))
insert into @tt (RepID)values (11)
insert into @tt (RepID)values (22)


declare @target table (ID varchar(10),Name varchar(10),Repid INT )
INSERT INTO @target (ID,Name,Repid)

select t.ID,t.Name,tt.RepID from @t t,@tt tt

select * from @target
```